# Upload sub-folders to FTP in Windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd, ftp, directory

I have to upload an entire folder commandline on Windows. I can't get it to upload the subdirectories including it's files.

```
ftp
open snuzzer.dk
username
password
mput *.*
```

This only uploads all files in the root.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be to use ncftpput with the -R option.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very simple. Do you know if there's an option to only upload if local file is newer than remote file? I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Comment: I don't believe so. The 'rsync' program can do that, but it needs to be on both client and server.

Comment: also, you could set up a script that uses a marker file to use with the find command: "find . -type f -newer marker" to make a list of files to send. then "touch marker" after the upload. but that gets complicated. and anyway, you're on windows not unix, so installing all that would be a hassle unless you use cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

Windows command-line `ftp.exe` client does not support operations with (sub)folders.

You have to use a 3rd-party FTP client.

---

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) you can use:

```
winscp.com /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "put *" ^
    "exit"
```

There's a guide for [converting Windows `ftp.exe` script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp). Though easier is to have [WinSCP GUI generate the script or batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a batch script that creates a command file for `ftp` and then issues the `ftp` command with that file.

Something liek this:

```
@ECHO OFF    
ECHO open snuzzer.dk>command.txt
ECHO username>>command.txt
ECHO password>>command.txt

FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /b /s /a-d "%1"') DO (
   ECHO put "%%A">>command.txt
)

ECHO close>>command.txt

ftp /s:command.txt
```

The `FOR` loop simply creates a list of all files recusively.

Comment: Tahnk you. I choose to use ncftpput. This seemed very simple.